# changing div value by using java script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to program a word of the day application however when i try to change the div value it doesn't change and here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Date.prototype.getDOY = function() {
var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
return Math.ceil((this - onejan) / 86400000);
};
var today = new Date();
var daynum = today.getDOY();
var week = "word1";
if (daynum>=300 & daynum<=307) {
document.write("hello")
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML=week
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="maindiv">
<br/>
<div id="p" class="indiv">Hello</div>

</div>
```

so can you give me any way to fix the problem

Comment: Why are you doing `document.write("hello")`?

Comment: I was trying to test if the if statement is working or not

Comment: Your code works fine without it http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gkpo80hw/

Comment: yeb it worked thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `document.write()` which will overwrite your existing HTML document, including `<div id="p"></div>`. So when you try to fetch it with `document.getElementById("p")` it will return `null`.

Comment: I have tried that sir but it didn't work, any other ideas ?

Comment: Did you remove `document.write("hello")`?

Comment: Also move the JavaScript code to before the end of `<body>`